# Error: "createRequire is not a function Referenced from: BaseConfig"

Tags: reactjs, npm, create-react-app

I have a freshly cloned repo created from the `create-react-app` template. I `npm install` to install the packages and then `npm start` to serve the files on localhost:3000. My coworker (the repo creator) is not having any issues.

However, I see the page flash for a second and then I get the following error:

> ```
> Failed to compile
> createRequire is not a function
> Referenced from: BaseConfig
> ```

The error message doesn't provide any other information to help trace which file it could be coming from.

I've tried the following to troubleshoot:

1. Deleting `node_modules` and `package-lock.json` and re-installing
2. Deleting the entire repo and re-cloning
3. Searching for 'createRequire' or 'BaseConfig' in project files found no results
4. Searching online for similar issues. None seem to have the same error I'm encountering.

Other details:
npm version 6.14.8
react version 17.0.1

Any idea where this error could be coming from or what steps I can do to trace it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> TL;DR Needed to upgrade node version

I tried `npx create-react-app` to confirm if the issue was with the template or with the project code. While doing that, I got a message that my package dependencies required a higher version of node (I was on v.10.4, the latest is v15.2.0).

Doing `brew upgrade` installed the latest version but didn't change the default node version across the system (ie: `node -v` still showed v10.4) but
doing `nvm install --lts` then `nvm alias-default [latest-version]` fixed my issue!

Comment: Avoid the hyphen i.e `nvm alias default 15.2.0`

Answer (score 1):

Some solutions are not worked for me. I uninstalled node.js and installed latest version. It worked!

Comment: It is basically an outdated node version issue so you are not wrong

Answer (score 0):

It could be connected with eslint in create-react-app

try to reinstall 'eslint' or 'eslint-config-react-app'
https://github.com/AtomLinter/linter-eslint/issues/1351

BaseConfig is a variable of the create-react-app react-scripts module
in node_modules/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.js

```
  formatter: require.resolve('react-dev-utils/eslintFormatter'),
                eslintPath: require.resolve('eslint'),
                resolvePluginsRelativeTo: __dirname,
                // @remove-on-eject-begin
                ignore: isExtendingEslintConfig,
                baseConfig: isExtendingEslintConfig
                  ? undefined
                  : {
                      extends: [require.resolve('eslint-config-react-app')],
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! It was somewhat related to eslint because a bunch of eslint related packages required the higher node version to work.

Answer (score 0):

For me, downgrade the `react-scripts` to latest 3.x version solved my problem. I could not update the NodeJS version, as I didn't have access to NodeJS server instance. Seems it fits better with React 16.x.

I'm running and building the app at NodeJS V10.0.0.

Answer (score 0):

I am a noob, but I just came across this very same error message in picking up where I previously had left off following a MERN stack tutorial.  During the break, I must have switched nvm versions, and thanks to this thread I was able to correct this.  From the terminal, I simply ran `nvm list`.  From the result, I could see that I was running an older version (10.9.0) but had a newer one (10.12.0) available to me, which I switched to by running `nvm use 10.12.0`. This resolved my issue.